# MySQL query to show multiple values in one field from many-many tables

Tags: mysql

I have tables:

TRUCKING_JOB: `trucking_id`, `driver`

```
Data: 
1, Jonah
2, Jim
3, Ron
```

MACHINES: `machine_id`, `machine_name`

```
Data:
1, Machine1
2, Machine2
3, Machine3
```

TRUCKING_MACHINE: `trucking_id`, `machine_id`

```
Data:
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
2, 1
2, 2
3, 1
3, 3
```

My question is, how can I get this query result using a single query string

trucking_id, driver, machine_names

For example:

```
1, Jonah, (Machine1, Machine2, Machine3)
```

The third column combine all machines.

Thanks for any help and advice..

Comment: Join the tables and use `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a 'GROUP BY' which has some special functions to do exactly what you need such as 'GROUP_CONCAT'.

```
SELECT 
  TRUCKING_JOB.trucking_id, 
  TRUCKING_JOB.driver, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(MACHINES.machine_name SEPARATOR ','
FROM TRUCKING_MACHINE
JOIN TRUCKING_JOB ON TRUCKING_MACHINE.trucking_id = TRUCKING_JOB.trucking_id
JOIN MACHINES ON TRUCKING_MACHINE.machine_id = MACHINES.machine_id
GROUP BY TRUCKING_JOB.trucking_id
```

You can add any WHERE clause statements before the GROUP BY.

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.. Here is my final query string based on @Eugene recommended query.

```
SELECT 
  TRUCKING_JOB.trucking_id AS TRUCKING_ID, 
  TRUCKING_JOB.driver AS DRIVER, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(MACHINES.machine_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS MACHINES
FROM TRUCKING_MACHINE
JOIN TRUCKING_JOB ON TRUCKING_MACHINE.trucking_id = TRUCKING_JOB.trucking_id
JOIN MACHINES ON TRUCKING_MACHINE.machine_id = MACHINES.machine_id
GROUP BY TRUCKING_JOB.trucking_id
```